# Firebase Functions Google Analytics Triggers Not Firing For Web Events

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I have added Firebase analytics to my web app but my analytics triggers onLog are not firing.

I added Firebase analytics to my site:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

Then I register events when the page loads:

```
const defaultAnalytics = window.firebase && window.firebase.analytics();
if (defaultAnalytics){
  defaultAnalytics.logEvent('viewedNote', { noteId});
}
```

I can see events are registering in the Firebase console:
[image]

I have firebase functions set up to fire when these events are registered.

```
 exports.logViewedNote = functions.analytics.event('viewedNote').onLog((event) => {
  console.log(event)
 });
```

However, I am not seeing any logs in Firebase console for these functions. Aka, they are not firing. The events I'm listening to have been setup as conversion events for over 72 hours, and still nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you've followed all the documentation and it just doesn't work, then file a bug report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

Firebase support let me know Google Analytics triggers do not work with web analytics yet:

> "...the only products that are supported for Web via Google Analytics as of the moment are Cloud Messaging and Remote Config...
>       We’re continuously working on this, but I can’t provide any details or timelines as to when this could be available."

Hopefully, more web analytics features will roll out over the next few months.